# Excluir controles Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Preciso remover os controles DevExpress de um projeto devido projeto possuir estes componentes e não ter a licença do software.

Já excluí os componentes e as referencias mas ao tentar compilar aparece o erro: `Não foi possível localizar o arquivo c:\projetos\Sw\My Project\licences.licx`.

Já executei o Clean do menu Build mas o erro continua.

Como faço para excluir esta referência?

Comment: Qual o complemento do erro? Você está usando algum componente? Segundo [este tópico no fórum da DevPress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q452887), se estiver usando algum componente, o arquivo será criado novamente.

Comment: Eu removi todos os componentes DevExpress do projeto e componentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Botão direito no `.csproj`, opção **Unload Project**.

Novamente clique com o botão direito em cima do arquivo `.csproj`, opção "Edit SeuProjeto.csproj".

Procure por `licenses.licx`. Exclua todas as tags que tenham a ver com este nome.

Salve, clique com o botão direito no arquivo `.csproj`, opção **Reload Project**.

Experimente fazer um *Build*.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano, funcionou 100%